# can we change the color of node in react + graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphviz, react-graph-vis

I am using the below package. I have the first and last node. I want to change its background color.

```
nodes: [
      { id: 'Node 1', label: "Node 1", title: "node 1 tootip text" ,first:true},
      { id: 2, label: "Node 2", title: "node 2 tootip text" },
      { id: 3, label: "Node 3", title: "node 3 tootip text" },
      { id: 4, label: "Node 4", title: "node 4 tootip text" },
      { id: 5, label: "Node 5", title: "node 5 tootip text",last:true }
    ],
```

first node have `first:true` and `last:true`. can we change their background color ?? **like red and green** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-graph-vis

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yvpt5j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `color` property

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c9tnhw)

```
 const graph = {
    nodes: [
      { id: 'Node 1', label: "Node 1", title: "node 1 tootip text" ,first:true,  color: "red" },
      { id: 2, label: "Node 2", title: "node 2 tootip text" },
      { id: 3, label: "Node 3", title: "node 3 tootip text" },
      { id: 4, label: "Node 4", title: "node 4 tootip text" },
      { id: 5, label: "Node 5", title: "node 5 tootip text",last:true, color: 'Green' }
    ],
    edges: [
      { from: 'Node 1', to: 2,label:'dddddd' },
      { from: 'Node 1', to: 3,label:'adasd' },
      { from: 2, to: 4 },
      { from: 2, to: 5 }
    ]
  };
```

or you can change it dynamically on the basic of first and last properties

```js
    let obj = { nodes: [
          { id: 'Node 1', label: "Node 1", title: "node 1 tootip text" ,first:true},
          { id: 2, label: "Node 2", title: "node 2 tootip text" },
          { id: 3, label: "Node 3", title: "node 3 tootip text" },
          { id: 4, label: "Node 4", title: "node 4 tootip text" },
          { id: 5, label: "Node 5", title: "node 5 tootip text",last:true }
        ] };
    
    let updatedNodes = obj.nodes.map(( o ) => {
     let {first, last} = o;
     first ? o.color = 'red' : last ? o.color = 'green' : null;
     return {...o}
    });
    console.log(updatedNodes);
```

Comment: thanks for answer ...can we stop `zoom in and zoom out` and drag and drop ?

Answer (score 0):

Only add color:"red" and color:"green" on your nodes.

like this:

```
nodes: [
  { id: 'Node 1', label: "Node 1", title: "node 1 tootip text" ,first:true, color: "red"},
  { id: 2, label: "Node 2", title: "node 2 tootip text" },
  { id: 3, label: "Node 3", title: "node 3 tootip text" },
  { id: 4, label: "Node 4", title: "node 4 tootip text" },
  { id: 5, label: "Node 5", title: "node 5 tootip text",last:true, color: "green" }
],
```